# Empty string property that takes an argument

Tags: javascript

I need to answer the following question:

> Finally, to handle potential edge cases, add an empty string property
> (you will need to use quotes) which is a function that takes a single
> argument and returns that argument.

Here is what I have tried:

```
const spreadsheetFunctions = {
  
    sum,
    average,
    median,
    even: nums => nums.filter(isEven),
    someeven: nums => nums.some(isEven),
    everyeven: nums => nums.every(isEven),
    firsttwo: nums => nums.slice(0, 2),
    lasttwo: nums => nums.slice(-2),
    has2: nums => nums.includes(2),
    increment: nums => nums.map(num => num + 1),
    random: ([x, y]) => Math.floor(Math.random() * y + x),
    range: nums => range(...nums),
    nodupes: nums => [...new Set(nums).values()]
    "": (argument) => argument 
}
```

This didn't work though. Any ideas? This is for the freeCodeCamp project called "Learn Functional Programming by Building a Spreadsheet".

Comment: Is it a part of object? It should work. `let someObject = { "": arg => arg }` then you can try to `console.log` result. For example: `console.log(someObject[""]("Hello world"))`.

Comment: It is part of an object but that still doesn't work for this question.

Comment: What do you mean not working? It does not return passed value or you are getting some kind of error or is it just not what's expected of you to do?

Comment: freeCodeCamp is not accepting it as a valid answer

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Comment: You haven't provided any context, but I suspect you need to write a getter for this empty property.

Comment: solved. check my answer that i posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is just

```
"": x => x
```

For some reason it wanted the arguments to be x.

Comment: Someone should report that to FreeCodeCamp as a bug in their answer validation software.